# How to identify patterns/associations in a multiple choice question towards another variable?

Tags: pattern-recognition, association-measure, apriori

I have a dataset where with two questions. Question 1 is a multiple-choice question and asks the participants which treatment they took. E.g., treatment A, treatment B, treatment C etc.

Question 2 asks if the well-being improved (Yes/No).

So participants may have taken several treatments. Consequently, I do not know if their well-being has improved which treatment caused the improvement.

I already tried to make Itemsets, e.g. (treatment A, treatment B, yes)(treatment B, treatment C, no), and applied apriori algorithm to find some associations or patterns.

However, are there other methods to analyse this and find out if some treatment is associated with the outcome?

P.S.: Chi-square is not appropriate as the treatments are not exclusive. Further, I am aware that the design of these questions is not ideal to identify the effect of a treatment. However, I just got this dataset and now have to take it as it is.

Comment: I provided an answer, but in case you find it too general, I'd suggest to edit your question so other people can offer more specific advice. In particular, you should mention what is your sample size, how many treatments there are, and the study design (e.g. how the treatments have been assigned to people in the sample). You should also rewrite the title of your question, to mention that you're looking for a method to find if a treatment (among multiple, possibly co-occurring treatments) is associated with a binary outcome. The current title may be not very obvious in this regard.

Comment: I'd also suggest to add the tags [tag:logistic] and [tag:multiple-regression] to your question, to elicit answers from people who follow these tags and may provide you with good advice.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 is not really a single question, but multiple dichotomous questions hidden under the guise of one question. These hidden questions are: Treatment A: Yes/No, Treatment B: Yes/No, etc.

Consequently, you *might* be able use them as multiple independent variables in something like a [logistic regression model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression), possibly with interactions between treatments. However, you have to correctly specify the model (e.g. do you want to model every possible interactions between treatments?), and your sample size should be adequate for the model complexity. In addition, if this is not an experimental design, it may be particularly challenging to make causal inference.

Besides these possible issues, here's a more mundane one: if checkboxes have been used to ask respondents these questions (instead of explicitly asking "yes/no"), it may be very difficult to distinguish between someone who answered "no" and someone who didn't respond. In other words, it is hard to know if they didn't take the treatment, or if they took the treatment but refused or omitted to check the corresponding box.

In this case, it could introduce bias into your analysis. If respondents had to pick treatments in a long list of options, or if there was a long series of questions before, the answers may be particularly prone to this issue.